# How can I remove all keywords from Adobe Bridge?

Tags: metadata, keywords, adobe, adobe-bridge

I have started using bridge and in doing so reorganized my keyword list a number of times, without being aware that if all the files with that keyword aren't selected, you end up with duplicate keywords (in italics).

I have tried removing these italicized keywords in multiple ways while selecting all the photos. Making them persisting and deleting, clicking the checkbox so no files have the keyword and then deleting. The only way that works is going through each file one at a time and removing the keywords. Is there no way I can completely start again, wiping all keyword data from the photos and from Bridge or do I have to work through each photo one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is:

1. Do a keyword search for the moved word;
2. Select all the images that come up;
3. On the keywords panel, un-tick the italicised version of the keyword;
4. With the images still selected, tick the moved version of the keyword.
5. Delete the italicised work in the keywords panel.

So that way you keep all the images under the correct keyword and delete the double-up keyword label.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: tbh, it's far from convenient. any updates after 7 years?